# I am having trouble formating the date in the excel sheet I am reading from using C#

Tags: c#

/* all of these are output fields that are being parsed with input fields from an excel*/

public void Import()
{

```
        CRMRecord r;
        DataTable dtCarrierData = LoadXL(true);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtCarrierData.Rows)
        {
            

            r = new CRMRecord();
            r.FleetID = "TN045";
            r.BillingCompany = "TCH";
            r.StationCode = ParseField<string>(dr, "fp_truckstopcode");
            r.DriverID = ParseField<string>(dr, "FP_unitnumber");

            r.TransactionDate = ParseField<string>(dr, "FP_transdate"); /* I have a standard output and transaction date = FP_Transdate basically but the trouble is the FP_transdate format coming in as "yyddMM" Ex:210120, 210121, there are 5 more just like those in the column (FP_transdate) */
            DateTime FP_transdate = DateTime.ParseExact("yyddMM", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); /* here is where I have an output that is reading an excel everything is reading fine except for date, i get an error saying "Processing exception - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."  It is not formatted correctly in the input(its "yy/dd/MM", I need it to be "MM/dd/yyyy" and it comes from an outside source so I can't just change the cell value in excel to date. */
            FP_transdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
           
            r.Ref1 = ParseField<string>(dr, "FP_truckstopinvnum");

            decimal trcFuelCost = ParseField<decimal>(dr, "trcFuelCost");
            decimal reefFuelCost = ParseField<decimal>(dr, "reefFuelCost");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: There is no input date value provided in `DateTime.ParseExact("yyddMM", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); `

Comment: Where "yyddMM" is after ParseExact??  the input would come from FP_transdate thats the excel column. So replace "yyddMM" with "FP_transdate"?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

r.TransactionDate = ParseField(dr, "FP_transdate").Substring(2, 2) + "/" + ParseField(dr, "FP_transdate").Substring(4, 2) + "/" + "20" + ParseField(dr, "FP_transdate").Substring(0, 2);

There may be a better way to write this but this worked for me.